# Delphi - TQuery .AsString to return 0 or 1 for Boolean field values

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7

How can i get Delphi 7 to return a '0' or '1' when the FieldType of a TQuery descendant's Field is a ftBoolean? By default this returns 'TRUE' or 'FALSE', that is

`Query1.Fields[0].AsString` would return `'0'`, not `'FALSE'`

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone, unfortunately i was hoping for a global mod to set while i perform a function call. In this instance i have no idea what type the field is going to be and was hoping for a quick set, then revert solution, without having to check if the field is a TBooleanField. Oh well :)

Comment: Basically my aim is to export ANY query to a CSV file using the AsString method of the TField. I do not set this query design time, only at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears that the only way to do this is to check for every TField:

if `(Query1.Fields[i] is TBooleanField)` and then use one of the methods provided above.

There is no global `TField.AsString` hack as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
(Query1.Fields[0] as TBooleanField).DisplayValues := 'TRUE;FALSE';
```

to set a string in the form of 'TRUE;FALSE' (or '1;0'). This allows you to define what values AsString will return.

If you added the field in design time, and/or you got yourself a boolean field component, you can use that too, without the typecast:

```
Query1YourBooleanField.DisplayValues := 'TRUE;FALSE';
```

By the way, it's not the query that returns '0', not is it the query that 'is' ftBoolean. These are the fields in the query that represent fields in the table or query result set.

Comment: Is there any way to do this for all fields (without having to do 0-FieldCount-1)? That is, i do not know exactly which field will be a boolean, but IF it is i would like it to return '0' or '1'

Comment: Hmm, this procedure doesnt seem to exist on Delphi7

Answer (score 2):

Why not simple use Query1.Fields[0].AsInteger if you want a numerical representation for the boolean ? I think that should work ...

Comment: This will give me an integer unfortunately. My ultimate goal is to export a (any) query to a CSV file, but to set options globally to change the output

Answer (score 2):

Modify `STextFalse` and `STextTrue` resourcestrings in 'dbconsts.pas'. You can put a modified version of the file to your project folder, or go about just like localizing your application.

If you want to modify the strings at run-time you can use the below ([credit](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=31779)):

```
[...]
implementation

uses
  dbconsts;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure SetResourceString(ResStringRec: pResStringRec; NewStr: string);
var
  OldProtect: DWORD;
begin
  if ResStringRec = nil then
    Exit;
  VirtualProtect(ResStringRec, SizeOf(ResStringRec^),
                 PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @OldProtect) ;
  ResStringRec^.Identifier := Integer(NewStr) ;
  VirtualProtect(ResStringRec, SizeOf(ResStringRec^), OldProtect, @OldProtect) ;
end;

const
  TextFalse = '0';
  TextTrue = '1';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetResourceString(@STextFalse, TextFalse);
  SetResourceString(@STextTrue, TextTrue);
  [...]
```

Comment: This was what i was thinking, but im not sure if i can call this x number of times in my application to set to '0,1' then back to 'TRUE,FALSE'?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use this trick in such situations:

```
const DigitBool: array[Boolean] of string = ['0', '1'];
//and than
Caption := DigitBool[Query1.Fields[0].Value];
```

Comment: You can do that, but it won't change the behaviour of AsString, which is just as easy to accomplish, and can even be changes in design time, without writing extra code. And this code will fail miserably if the field isn't a boolean field. Otherwise, the solution with the boolean indexed array is a nice one that I like to use a lot.

Comment: Yes this doesnt change the behaviour of AsString :(

Comment: This code works well with any boolean variables, not just fields. That's why I like it.